# How to get the SMILES from structure without software?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reference-request, cheminformatics

Usually I use online programs and structure drawing tools to find the SMILES of a compound. How to find the SMILES without software? Where to find resources to learn it?

Comment: How could be software anything but logical...

Comment: @Mithoron My bad, I guess logical isn't the right word. How do you find SMILES without software.

Comment: @PrittBalagopal In the mirror, ;-) "cheese" .

Comment: @Buttonwood Molecules aren't gonna be smiling for my camera :).

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/47242/what-is-this-smiles-notation-csicc-11 https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/20486/what-would-be-smiles-notation-for-a-compound-with-delocalized-bonding

Comment: You simply need to know how SMILES works.

Comment: @Mithoron Could you direct me to sources that explain how SMILES work?

Comment: @PrittBalagopal - If you see the links above, there are related questions. There's the Daylight SMILES [tutorial](http://daylight.com/dayhtml_tutorials/languages/smiles/) and [theory](http://www.daylight.com/dayhtml/doc/theory/theory.smiles.html) and [OpenSMILES specification](http://opensmiles.org/opensmiles.html) all from Google searches. The concept of SMILES was to be easy to write by a human, once the syntax is understood.

Comment: here a brief tutorial http://molecularmodelingbasics.blogspot.dk/2016/05/a-brief-introduction-to-smiles-and-inchi.html

Comment: In this website you can type SMARTS and it generates a visual representation:
https://smartsview.zbh.uni-hamburg.de